# Nested loop to fill matrix

Tags: loops, matrix

Noob here... I want to use a nested for-loop to set up a matrix of the following kind:

1 2 3 4
0 3 5 7
0 0 8 12
(just an example, the numbers do not grow incrementally)

i.e. each number is the sum of the element above and the element above to the left. Which means that on row i, all elements until column i are zero.
The actual numbers will depend on a starting value n., and the matrix will have the shape n*n.

I have the starting values for the first row, and need to find a way to go through each row and fill up every element.

```
def function(x,n):
    M=zeros([n,n])  #create the matrix
    a=(1+x)/2       #formula to set starting value 
    g=sqrt(x)       
    for i in range(n): #fill up first row
        M[0,i]=a       #change value in cell 
        a=(a+g)/2      #set a new value for 'a' and 'g' 
        g=sqrt(a*g)
        for j in range(n): #Do the same for each row
            M[j:n,???]=M[j-1,???]+M[j,???]
```

But here I'm stuck.. I can't find a way to have the formula run through the elements on each line.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the logic that you use to fill the first, row, but this should work to fill the remainder.

```
from math import sqrt
from numpy import zeros

def function(x,n):
    M = zeros([n,n])  #create the matrix
    a = (1 + x) / 2       #formula to set starting value 
    g = sqrt(x)       
    for i in range(n): #fill up first row
        M[0,i] = a       #change value in cell 
        a = (a + g) / 2      #set a new value for 'a' and 'g' 
        g = sqrt(a * g)
    for row in range(1,n): # iterate over rows, skip the first
        for col in range(row,n): #iterate over columns, skip the first few
            M[row, col] = M[row - 1, col - 1] + M[row - 1, col]
    return M
```